# I am updating RaspiBolt - Where is my old electrs config?

Tags: electrum, raspberry-pi

I am updating my RaspiBolt according to this [guide](https://raspibolt.org/electrs.html). Unfortunately, the guide changed a lot since my last update. It is still great, though!

I am upgrading from `v0.8.10` to `v0.9.3` and somewhere in between the path for `electrs` config changed to `/data/electrs/electrs.conf`.

Where was it before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the old config with `systemctl edit --full-edit electrs.service` in the line

`ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/electrs --conf /mnt/bitcoin/electrs/electrs.conf`.

The location of the config changed because the guide introduced a different [setup](https://raspibolt.org/system-configuration.html#data-directory) for the data storage. In the old setup user `bitcoin` was necessary. This user is now deactivated for interaction and just used by the bitcoin service. Data is now stored in `/data` which is owned by `bitcoin:bitcoin` and the user `admin` is in the group `bitcoin`, making changes possible with user `admin`.

I was wondering why `/data` is not mounted from the external SSD/HDD. Reason is the guide now suggests to run the whole operating system from the SSD.

Other important notes for updating `electrs` can be found [here](https://github.com/romanz/electrs/blob/master/doc/upgrading.md). Although it is not stated as necessary, using the old `verbose =` option in the config did result in a failed startup. I had to just use `log_filters =`.

Also, I had to update `bitcoin.conf` with `whitelist=download@127.0.0.1` so that `electrs` can get a connection.